# Stord procedure to filter staff in terms of paygrade and mode of employment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, account

I am trying to create a Stored procedure to allow me to sort my staff in to 3 distinct catergories that can then be paired up to a relevant account in the database. I am new to writing stored procedures so I don't know if this is syntactically correct. Basically when run I want the stored proc to check to see if the employee is full time and the job role they have and then assign them to the following accounts - HighIncomeC00CCW, LowIncomeC0ECCW & PartTimeC0ECCX. This is what I have so far -

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStaffPay]
@Isfulltime = bit 
@Jobrole = varchar(20)


BEGIN

IF   (@Isfulltime = 1
      AND @Jobrole = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10)

      BEGIN 
      Account = HighIncomeC00CCW 
      END

ELSE IF (@Isfulltime = 1
      AND @Jobrole = 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 17 or 18 or 19 or 20)

      BEGIN 
      Account = LowIncomeC0ECCW
      END

ELSE (@Isfulltime = 0)
      Then

      BEGIN 
      Account = PartTimeC0ECCX
      END
END
```

Comment: If the employees in are in table then you can just select from the table and use a `case` statement - this will be faster than writing procedural code.

Comment: Oh BTW when you run that SP do you get an error? If so what is it? If you want to know if its correct.... run it!

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that EmployeeType (Full/Part time) and JobRole are a column in a Staff table? What is the schema of the table you are querying?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler, Yeah the EmployeeType (Full/Part time) and JobRole are a column in a Staff table. What do you mean by schema?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry i am new to SPs, how would a case statement look?

Comment: NoSaidTheCompiler has an exact example of what I'm mentioning. From  what I can tell there is no reason to use a stored procedure but we don't have any background so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what else would be used instead of a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample that you could use to figure out the solution. You could learn more about Case statement [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) (msdn documentation). Hope it helps you to figure out the solution you need.

```
      --This is to drop the temp table if it already exists.
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempStaff') is not null
begin 
    drop table #tempStaff;
end;

create table #tempStaff 
(StaffId int primary key, 
StaffName varchar(100), 
StaffType varchar(100), 
StaffRole varchar(100))

insert into #tempStaff
values
(1,'james1', 'full', 'role1')
,(2,'james2', 'full', 'role2')
,(3,'james3', 'part', 'role4')
,(4,'james4', 'part', 'role4')

--the code above is to create a sample table
--the code below is an example that you need to learn from to get 
--your stored proc do what you are trying.

select StaffId
,StaffName
,StaffType 
,StaffRole  
, case 
when (StaffType = 'full' and StaffRole in ('role1', 'role2')) then 'HighIncome' 
when (StaffType = 'part' and StaffRole in ('role3', 'role4')) then 'LowIncome'
--you could add as many 'when' as you need depending on your scenario.
end as AccountType
from #tempStaff
```

And if you need more help, please specify on which part you got stuck (you might have to make a comment to your original post).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will this work the way it has to? I need three account types 1 for full time = yes and highIncome, 1 for full time = yes and low income and one for part time

Comment: Well, I answered it to the best of my understanding of your question. this isn't going to be an exact solution, you might have to modify the condition inside the 'when' clause. This hopefully gives you enough ground to build upon. Update the question with what you've tried and what didn't work and I will help you.